# Image not loading correctly in app

Tags: ios, uiimage

My app lets the user select the photo from camera roll or take the photo, the app saves the photo locally and then goes to the next view controller and loads the image that was just saved and displayed on an image view.

This is the code that I used to get the image the user wanted and sent it to my send picture method.

```
 UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
[self saveImage:image];
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"switch" sender:nil];
```

Which is this:

```
-(void)saveImage: (UIImage*)image{
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png"];
        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        printf("image saved");
    }
```

That code ran because it printed the image was saved. The app goes to the next view and this is how I set up my viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //[imageViewPreview setImage:self.secondImage];
    //imageViewPreview.image = self.secondImage;
}
```

I commented out both ways that I've tried but neither of those works. This is how I was trying to get my secondImage to load:

```
-(UIImage* )secondImage{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png"];
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    printf("image loaded");
    return image;
}
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried `[imageViewPreview setImage:[self secondImage]]` instead of `imageViewPreview.image = self.secondImage` ?

Comment: @Unkn0wn.Bit that should be the same thing.

Comment: Yes, that should be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this much simpler. In your second view controller add a public UIImage property. Then import the second controller into the first one. Then in prepareForSegue set it the image like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"switch"]) {
        ClassOfDEstinationController *destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destinationController.image = image;
    }

}
```